# Call program windows in my application like a child

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application and i wan to call another program into it, like
notepad.so when i minimize the notepad, or maximize, it must rest in
my application.

I open application maximized, and want open notepad like a child.

I use this code

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 private static extern int SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

 [DllImport("User32")]
 private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

 private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;

 Process p = new Process();


 private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   p.StartInfo.FileName = "NOTEPAD.EXE";
   p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
   p.Start();
   // change parent window and maximize inside the form
   SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
   ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
  }
```

But don't work!!! ()

Comment: No, i don't get error, when i minimize the notepad, or maximize, it must rest in my application.

Comment: You can't do that with C#. You might be able to it with C++. If you're trying this is just for fun, then I'd recommend having fun with something else!

Comment: Thanks, I want open notepad, without user can open another process in app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do this, but it is fiendishly difficult to get it right. Raymond Chen covered the topic in some detail: [Is it legal to call have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx)

> A customer liaison asked whether it was legal to use Set­Parent to
>   create a parent/child relationship between windows which belong to
>   different processes.
>
> ......
>
> So yes, it is technically legal, but if you create a cross-process
>   parent/child or owner/owned relationship, the consequences can be very
>   difficult to manage. And they become near-impossible to manage if one
>   or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in
>   a cross-process window tree. (I often see this question in the context
>   of somebody who wants to grab a window belonging to another process
>   and forcibly graft it into their own process. That other process was
>   totally unprepared for its window being manipulated in this way, and
>   things may stop working. Indeed, things will definitely stop working
>   if you change that other window from a top-level window to a child
>   window.)

So, you can do this. But it is not easy, and absolutely not recommended. It's hard enough to do in C++, but from the managed world you are just asking for pain. The most sane advice we can give you is to find a different solution to your problem.

Comment: I have never used c++ program. I want to limit the access of user to all program of window, and can use notepad only

Comment: I do not understand that comment. Could you elaborate.

Comment: I have a app that run in startup windows, and open a notepad. I want to limited user that do't open another application, don't shutdown windows and ...

Comment: That sounds like a different question altogether.

Comment: It is my problem, and my solution is : when run app `Call program windows in my application like a child` that limit user .

Comment: Your solution will not work. I suggest you find a different solution that will work.